# Binding works without INotifyPropertyChanged, why?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

This is how we do it normally:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _test;
    public string Test
    {
        get { return _test; }
        set
        {
            _test = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
}
```

Now our property can be used by multiple elements in the view, e.g.:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Test, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}" />
```

Changing value in `TextBox` will update content of `TextBlock`. As well as we can set value in the view model and view will update it automatically.

If we write view model like this

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

then **the view is still working** (e.g. changing value in `TextBox` will update `TextBlock`). Of course it's not possible to easily update `Test` value from view model anymore (no more event to rise). But my question is about view: **Why view is able to work**? Does it construct something more in background or is it a logic which checks for something?

Comment: Hmm..i'm not sure I understand your example. You say that if you don't implement `OnPropertyChanged` _the view is still working (e.g. changing value in TextBox will update TextBlock)_ Of course, the view updates the Source (that's why you set up when in `UpdateSourceTrigger`). But in the second case, if you change the value of Test in your viewmodel, the View won't be notifyed and you won't see that update in the view..

Comment: @Pikoh, my question is why replacing first view model with second one is still OK for the view. I just don't understand the logic behind what makes it working: we don't have full property, nothing is rised in setter, yet it works for the view without problem: binding to same property in multiple elements will properly track when its value is changed.

Comment: If you want to take a look at a full working example for this magical behavior, you can take a look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46803196/1977871).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [...] you are encountering a
>   another hidden aspect of WPF, that's it WPF's data binding engine will
>   data bind to PropertyDescriptor instance which wraps the source
>   property if the source object is a plain CLR object and doesn't
>   implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface. And the data binding
>   engine will try to subscribe to the property changed event through
>   PropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged() method. And when the target data
>   bound element change the property values, data binding engine will
>   call PropertyDescriptor.SetValue() method to transfer the changed
>   value back to the source property, and it will simultaneously raise
>   ValueChanged event to notify other subscribers (in this instance, the
>   other subscribers will be the TextBlocks within the ListBox.
>
> And if you are implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, you are fully
>   responsible to implement the change notification in every setter of
>   the properties which needs to be data bound to the UI. Otherwise, the
>   change will be not synchronized as you'd expect.

See: [Data binding without INotifyPropertyChanged](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9365bb6a-b411-4967-9a03-ae2a810fb215/data-binding-without-inotifypropertychanged?forum=wpf)

Comment: Ok, so view subscribes for each such binding to `ValueChanged` event and in turn rises notification by itself when updating source. That explains how it works, thanks.