# Binding UI directly to API model

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

[Binding works without INotifyPropertyChanged, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972605/binding-works-without-inotifypropertychanged-why)

Is it a bad practice to bind my UI to HTTP API model directly without creating a separate view model?

The only disadvantage is it won't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so UI won't update when you change the property from your code - but what if you don't need to update your property from your code?

This is my API response model:

```
public class EventResponseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public string ArgbColor { get; set; } // should bind to Brush
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Person> Attendees { get; set; }
}
```

In the model above I have `ArgbColor` that need to be bound to `Brush` in XAML. I could probably create `StringToBrushConverter : IValueConverter` to make it work instead of creating a separate view model.

Is this always preferred to create a separate view model, map to it and then bind to it?

For editing, I would still have a separate VM and use a composition like:

```
public class EventVM 
{
    public EventResponseModel EditedEvent { get; set; }
    // available locations etc., commands for saving
}
```

Comment: "Is it a bad practice?" - no, not in my opinion. I would however recommend `public Color ArgbColor { get; set; }` and bind a SolidColorBrush's Color property.

Comment: `Color` needs a reference to `System.Media` or `PresentationCore`. This model is used on the server so `string` is the best type.

Comment: Does `ArgbColor` Value contains html clr codes ? like this( #1A85CD )?

Comment: @AvinashReddy yes, #AARRGGBB. It's not a problem to convert it using `BrushConverter`

Comment: Then why cant u just bind the string to color i mean `Background="{Binding ArgbColor }"` Like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a bad practice to bind my UI to HTTP API model directly without creating a separate view model?

Not if you are and will be able to use the model class exactly as-is in your GUI application. Then there is no reason to create a view model wrapper just for the sake of it, since you basically have a dependency upon the API anyway.

> Is this always preferred to create a separate view model, map to it and then bind to it?

No, not always. If you for example were to display a couple of hundreds or thousands of event responses in a grid of some kind, you don't want to invoke a converter for each item. In this case it would be better to wrap the model and bind directly to a UI friendly Brush property or similar. So it all depends on your requirements. But binding directly to domain objects isn't always a bad idea.