# Observe a property change of another class

Tags: c#, .net

I want to observe a property of a class that did not implement  `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Is there any way to achieve that? It would be great if I could create some generic class or base class to inherit from it and to work with.

Comment: Why can't you just implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Are you simply looking for a [better way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1315621/1997232) to implement it?

Comment: You can try to use [same approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40972605/1997232)  as bindings in wpf do, when data context doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. You still need to rise notification somewhere though.

Comment: @Sinatr The fact is I did not create these classes something like built-in Classes and I don't want just WPF I want it in console or DLL.

Comment: Can you be more specific? It looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295).

Comment: @Sinatr ok I have a Process object in this case it is the brave browser I want to know about its threads and perform a task every time that changes.

Comment: "brave browser"? What task you want to perform? What means if thread changes? Single process can spawn many threads, what you want to know? Just the number of threads? Do you want to debug or something else?

Comment: Ask yourself [5 whys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_whys) and write the root cause please.

Comment: @Sinatr I'm trying to create a custom task manager  and want to log some detailed information of processes the thing is its changing in time, in the thread part I want to know how many thread is running and current priority and uptime of them

Comment: I believe for such tasks you just need to poll values and that's how windows task manager works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't change your class where you need the event, you can use this wrapper:

```
public class NotifyPropertyChangedWrapper<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly T item;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public NotifyPropertyChangedWrapper(T item)
    {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public TProp Get<TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> exp)
    {
        MemberExpression memExp = exp.Body as MemberExpression;
        var property = memExp.Member as PropertyInfo;
        return (TProp)property.GetValue(item);
    }

    public void Set<TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> exp, TProp newValue)
    {
        MemberExpression memExp = exp.Body as MemberExpression;
        var property = memExp.Member as PropertyInfo;
        property.SetValue(item, newValue);
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(item, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property.Name));
    }
}
```

If you use it, you only set and get the properties via the wrapper's set and get methods. If you do so, the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event will be invoked. Here is an example usage

```
class Test
{
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

var notify = new NotifyPropertyChangedWrapper<Test>(new Test());
notify.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.PropertyName);
notify.Set(x => x.SomeProperty, 10);
Console.WriteLine(notify.Get(x => x.SomeProperty));
```

Here is an online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oVE4WW

Comment: @sj13 Please be aware that it is more some proof of conecpt than code that should be used in acutal software. For example, if you call the Get and Set methods with an arbitrary expression, a NullReferenceException will be thrown. Also, one could consider to invoke the PropertyChanged event only if newValue is different from the property's current value and so on.